# How to save multiple values in custom post type from front end to back end

Tags: plugin-development, metabox, page-template

i created a plugin in WordPress ,
i created custom post type called "invoices" 
here it's the code

```
add_action('init', 'invoices_register'); 

function invoices_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Invoices', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Invoice', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New Invoice ', 'Device'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Invoice'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Invoice'),
    'new_item' => __('New Invoice'),
    'view_item' => __('View Invoices'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Invoices'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No Invoices'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Invoices Here'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor')
  );

register_post_type( 'invoices' , $args );
}
```

Then i created repeated meta box here it's the code

```
    <?php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'mb_add_custom_box' );

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'mb_save_postdata' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function mb_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'invocie_details',
        __( 'Invocie Details', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'mb_inner_custom_box',
        'invoices');
}

/* Prints the box content */
function mb_inner_custom_box() {
    global $post;
    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'mbMeta_noncename' );
    ?>
    <div id="meta_inner">
    <?php

    //get the saved meta as an array
    $invocies = get_post_meta($post->ID,'invocies',false);
  //  print_r($invocies);

    $c = 0;
    if ( count( $invocies ) > 0 ) {
        if(!empty($invocies)){
            foreach( $invocies as $track_val ) {

                foreach( $track_val as $track ) {
                    //var_dump($track);
                    if ( isset( $track['service'] ) || isset( $track['price'] ) || isset( $track['status']) || isset( $track['client']) )  {
                        printf( '<p>invocie service <input type="text" name="invocies[%1$s][service]" value="%2$s" /> &nbsp;&nbsp; invocie price : <input type="text" name="invocies[%1$s][price]" value="%3$s" /><br> invocie staus : <input type="text" name="invocies[%1$s][status]" value="%4$s" />&nbsp;&nbsp; invocie client : <input type="text" name="invocies[%1$s][client]" value="%5$s" /><span class="remove">%6$s</span></p>', $c, $track['service'], $track['price'],$track['status'],$track['client'], __( 'Remove Invocie' ) );
                        $c = $c +1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
    }

    ?>


<span id="here"></span>
<span class="add"><?php _e('Add Invoice'); ?></span>
<script>
    var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var count = <?php echo $c; ?>;
        $(".add").click(function() {
            count = count + 1;

            $('#here').append('<p>invocie service <input type="text" name="invocies['+count+'][service]" value="" /> &nbsp;&nbsp; invocie price : <input type="text" name="invocies['+count+'][price]" value="" /><br> invocie staus : <input type="text" name="invocies['+count+'][status]" value="" />&nbsp;&nbsp; invocie client : <input type="text" name="invocies['+count+'][client]" value="" /><span class="remove">Remove Invocie</span></p>' );
            return false;
        });
        $(".remove").live('click', function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
    </script>
</div><?php

}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function mb_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
    // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times
    if ( !isset( $_POST['mbMeta_noncename'] ) )
        return;

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['mbMeta_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

    $invocies = $_POST['invocies'];

    update_post_meta($post_id,'invocies',$invocies);
}
```

then i created custom page template to insert new invoice from front end but the problem is when creating a new post the save not working with meta box here the code

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) == '1') {
                            $post_title = $_POST['tile'];
                            //$post_category = $_POST['cat'];
                            //$post_content = $_POST['post_content'];

                            $new_post = array(
                                 // 'ID' => '',
                                  'post_type' => 'invoices',
                                  //'post_author' => $user->ID, 
                                  //'post_category' => array($post_category),
                                 // 'post_content' => $post_content, 
                                 // 'post_title' => $post_title,
                                  'post_status' => 'publish',
                                  'meta_input' => array(
                                    'invociesp[service]' => $_POST['service'],
                                    'invocies[price]' => $_POST['price'],
                                    'invocies[status]' => $_POST['status'],
                                    'invocies[client]' => $_POST['client'],

                                   // '_flatsome_case_type' => $_POST['type'],

                                    //'city' => $post['city']
                                  )
                                );

                            $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post,true);
                            if($post_id ==true){
                              echo '<script language="javascript">alert("You Create a New case successfully")</script>';                            

                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[wp_insert_uses](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3790) (trac) the following loop to handle `meta_input`,

```
if ( ! empty( $postarr['meta_input'] ) ) {
  foreach ( $postarr['meta_input'] as $field => $value ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_ID, $field, $value );
  }
}
```

So if you change `meta_input` in your new post args to be like this,

```
'meta_input'  => array(
  'invocies'  => array(
    'service' => $_POST['service'],
    'price'   => $_POST['price'],
    'status'  => $_POST['status'],
    'client'  => $_POST['client'],
  ),
)
```

I think the data would then get saved correctly.